# Disable tablet mode entirely, how?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, tablet

It only causes bugs and I never use it. Willing to uninstall the functionality entirely.

Dell Inspiron 13 (i3-7100U/4GB/1TB) Product sku: QF9-01403

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: so do I ... Laptop keyboard disappears due to Tablet mode (and I do not even own a tablet). Disappointing bullshit configuration to enable tablet stuff on computers.